# SSRS Report Execution

Tags: sql-server-2014-express, ssrs-2014

I have a need to get the number of executions of a report(s) currently taking place. I thought, maybe, that the execution log view on the report server database inserted a new record each time a report execution started, with the report (item), item path, username, and timestart... then just updated the record with the timeend, the other time field values, etc. Unfortunately though, the record isn't inserted into the execution log (with all information) until the report run is complete.

I've done some google searching and find plenty about how to get information on report runs, but this is of course on report executions that have completed. I haven't been able to find anything on if there is a way, and how, to get a count of a particular report or reports that have executions currently in progress.

Just wondering if anyone has found, or come up with, some clever way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Microsoft support is that currently, there is nothing in the Reporting Services database that stores this information.